# Disabling warning about "require" function in JSHint

Tags: node.js, require, jshint

I'm writing some code for Node.js and I'm currently using JSHint to check over my code. However, when I use the `require` function to import modules, it says:

> 'require' is not defined.

How can I suppress the warning?

```
"use strict";
var express = require('express');   
var register = require('./routes/register');
```

Comment: try putting /*global require*/ to the file that you don't want to see, this worked for me

Answer (score 90):

jshint is not aware of node.js globals by default you need to inform it.

add this comment to the top:

`/* jshint node: true */`

Comment: I have already added that comment but still i have that issue.

Comment: can you post your settings comment

Comment: /*jshint node: true, bitwise:true, curly:true, forin:true, noarg:true,
 noempty:true, nonew:true, undef:true, strict:true, browser:true, node:true,  asi:false ,  vars:true, es5: true, evil: true, nomen: true */

Comment: I check it with jshint.com, it complained about `vars` as an options, try `/*jshint node: true, bitwise:true, curly:true, forin:true, noarg:true, noempty:true, nonew:true, undef:true, strict:true, browser:true, node:true, asi:false, es5: true, evil: true, nomen: true */`

Comment: Just to clarify, the comment should be added to the top of the *.js* file.

Answer (score 64):

We can set `node` as the global environment variable in JSHint's `.jshintrc` file

> This option defines globals available when your code is running inside of the Node runtime environment. Node.js is a server-side JavaScript environment that uses an asynchronous event-driven model. This option also skips some warnings that make sense in the browser environments but don't make sense in Node such as file-level use strict pragmas and console.log statements.

For more info http://jshint.com/docs/options/#node

```
{
   "node": true
}
```

Errors like `'require' is not defined`, `'console' is not defined`, `'module' is not defined` won't show up any more

Answer (score 7):

You can configure JSHint by adding "require" to the `.jshintrc` file.  For instance:

```
{
    "globals" : {
        "require": false
    }
}
```

Or you can define globals per specific file only by:

```
/* global require */
```

For more information about how to configure JSHint please read [JSHint Documentation](http://www.jshint.com/docs/)

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this answer and couldn't get anything to work in VSCode.  I got this to work:

1. Open JSON Settings file using the `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` via the Command Palette Window (Ctrl-Shift-P).
2. Add this section into the `settings.json` file:

   `{
     "jshint.options": {
       "esversion": 8, // This gets rid of some other warnings
       "node": true
     }
   }`